# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined - PokeApi

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to send text from the input text type to another component using params. But I got the next error

> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

I think using redirect is the best option to do it but I'm not sure.

```
export default class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {redirect: false , value: ''};
  }

    setRedirect(event) {
        this.setState({
          redirect: true,
          value: event.target.value
        });
      };
      renderRedirect = () => {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
          return <Redirect to={{
            pathname: `/pokemon/filtered/${this.state.value}`,
           }}/>;
        }
      };

    render() {
      return (
        <form>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.setRedirect()} />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to mistakes here

1. on the input line on the `onChange` you actually calling the function beacuse you added '()' 
   you should do:

```
 <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.setRedirect} />
```

second becuase this is a class you need to bind the function to that class on the constructor

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {redirect: false , value: ''};
    this.setRedirect = this.bind.setRedirect(this)
  }
```

or to simplify things use arrow function
because arrow function will **always** belongs to the object that called that function

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct way of binding an event handler in react is

   `<button onclick={activateLasers}>`
2. In javascript world. `this` is set to the caller by default. See `Function.prototype.bind` on MDN.
   To bind the class method to the class, you can 1. use public class fields syntax. 2. bind in the constructor.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html